# Limit XML data when converting JSON to XML - PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, rss

I am using this code to convert JSON to XML and everything is working fine. I am getting 200 records in the XML but i want to limit it to 50. I just want to create the XML file with latest 50 records. Instead of converting whatever we have in JSON to XML.

```
function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_numeric($key) ){
            $key = 'item'.$key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
        }
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
     }
}
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');
$json_file = file_get_contents("/directory/jsonfile.json");
$json_data = json_decode($json_file, true);
$json_data = array_slice((array)$json_data, 0, 50);
array_to_xml($json_data,$xml_data);
$result = $xml_data->asXML('/directory/xmlfile.xml');
```

## XML

This what my date node looks like:

```
<dateLastModified>1493913962397</dateLastModified>
```

## XML Sample Data

```
<data>
    <total>212</total>
    <start>0</start>
    <count>212</count>
    <data>
        <item0>
            <id>123</id>
            <title>abc-test1</title>
            <clientContact>
                <id>111</id>
                <firstName>abc</firstName>
                <lastName>xyz</lastName>
                <email>abc@xyz.ca</email>
            </clientContact>
            <isOpen>1</isOpen>
            <isPublic>1</isPublic>
            <isJobcastPublished>1</isJobcastPublished>
            <owner>
                <id>222</id>
                <firstName>testname</firstName>
                <lastName>testlastname</lastName>
                <address>
                    <address1>test address,</address1>
                    <address2>test</address2>
                    <city>City</city>
                    <state>state</state>
                    <zip>2222</zip>
                    <countryID>22</countryID>
                    <countryName>Country</countryName>
                    <countryCode>ABC</countryCode>
                </address>
                <email>test@test.com</email>
                <customText1>test123</customText1>
                <customText2>testxyz</customText2>
            </owner>
            <publicDescription>
                <p>test info</p>
            </publicDescription>
            <status>test</status>
            <dateLastModified>22222</dateLastModified>
            <customText4>test1</customText4>
            <customText10>test123</customText10>
            <customText11>test</customText11>
            <customText16>rtest</customText16>
            <_score>123</_score>
        </item0>
        <item1>
        ...
        </item1>
        ...
    </data>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of it depends on how much control you have over the data.  If you can sort the data by timestamp then you can add a counter and exit the loop when the the counter reaches 50.

```
function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
    $count = 0;
foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
    $count++;
    if($count == 50) {
       exit; //or return;
    }
    if( is_numeric($key) ){
        $key = 'item'.$key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
    }
    if( is_array($value) ) {
        $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
        array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
    } else {
        $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
    }
 }
}
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');
$json_file = file_get_contents("/directory/jsonfile.json");
$json_data = json_decode($json_file, true);
array_to_xml($json_data,$xml_data);
$result = $xml_data->asXML('/directory/xmlfile.xml');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I applied your solution but it didnt work. When i echo $count then it is rendering this "1234112312344567123412345678567891011..."

Comment: You may try $count = $count + 1;

Comment: No.. doesn't work. I also tried to limit the array to 50 before passing it to the aaray_to_xml function but that didnt slice the data.
$json_data = json_decode($json_file, true);
$json_data = array_slice((array)$json_data, 0, 50, true);
print_r (array_count_values($json_data));

Comment: If you could post a sample of your data, it would help.  You might need to add an IFstatement around the $count = $count + 1 where if(key == first_key) then increment counter

Comment: I have added a sample XML data in my post

Comment: Can you do when key == item50{ exit loop; } ?