# Getting 50 records from array php

Tags: php, arrays, json, slice

I have a json file which I am converting it to array and then trying to get 50 elements from the array.

But for some reason my code is not working and it is throwing 212 elements instead of 50

Please see my code below:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("/directory/jsonfile.json");
$json_data = json_decode($json_file, true);
$json_data = array_slice((array)$json_data, 0, 50);
print_r (array_count_values($json_data)); // this still showing 212 results
```

Comment: are you sure, `array_count_values` is what you want and not just `count`?

Comment: It's hard to believe for me that something shows `212 results` to you without seeing the actual input `$json_data`

Comment: Why are you casting `$json_data` to array? It's already an array.

Answer (score 3):

`count()` return an INT where `array_count_values()` return an ARRAY.

It looks like you need `count()` to get a count of array elements.

[PHP: array-count-values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

[PHP: count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: Thanks for your help, when i tried with count(), it showed 50 which is good but when i did output the entire array like this "print_r($json_data)" then it showed all the 212 results. I just want after slice(), it should show 50 records instead of 212?

Comment: @mak seems like, you have an nested array and each of that 50 items of the first layer have about 4-5 items inside.

Comment: @Philipp so my main goal is to convert json file to an array and then pick latest 50 items from an array and then convert it to xml. Here is code where i want to achieve that: But I am always getting 212 results. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334426/limit-xml-data-when-converting-json-to-xml-php/44334658?noredirect=1#comment75677788_44334658